# Compiling an OpenCV project using CMake on Cygwin, with OpenCV installed for Windows

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, cmake, raspberry-pi

### Situation:

I have a Windows 7 machine with **OpenCV for Windows** installed on it.
My OpenCV C++ projects work fine with Visual Studio 2010.

I want to run my existing OpenCV C++ projects to run on Raspberry Pi and on other Linux machines.

### Trouble

As a first step, I am trying to compile my .cpp & .h files using **GCC** on **Cygwin** on my Windows Machine. For this purpose I am trying to use **CMake package for Cygwin**, but **CMake** gives error that it cannot find OpenCV package. (error is listed below).

### Question:

1. Do i need to install **OpenCV package for Cygwin** separately for CMake to work ?
2. Is there a way to using my existing **OpenCV for Win** to work with CMake ?
3. What environment variables need to be set ?
   (Currently only a variable OPENCV_DIR is set to C:/opencv/build)

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4) 
PROJECT (testProj)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED )
set( NAME_SRC
    src/main.cpp    
    src/imgProcess.cpp    
)

set( NAME_HEADERS       
     include/imgProcess.h
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
link_directories( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
add_executable( testProj ${NAME_SRC} ${NAME_HEADERS} )

target_link_libraries( test ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

**cmake error**

```
$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Work/Project/cmaketest/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: 1) you need to rebuild the opencv **libs** with cygwin before you can do anything else, no, you can't use the visual studio libs for cygwin or on linux / PI.  3) OPENCV_DIR should be C:/opencv

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions. First you should get CMake finding your OpenCV, then you can think about further issues.

Comment: Thanks @berak. I understand. I will rebuild the libs for cygwin.

Comment: @usr1234567, thanls for the comment. But whats wrong with asking multiple questions ? they are all related to the same trouble. Infact, if one of the questions solves the trouble, thats all i need. other questions become irrelevant.

Comment: My answer helped with your CMake problem. If that would be your single answer, you'd accept my answer. Now I answered only one of your questions, so my answer does not cover all questions. Beside yourself after getting multiple such answers, the chances are low to find someone, who can answer all your questions. So this SO question will stay wirhout an acepted answer. You are right, berak is right and I was right. Who gets the props?

Comment: i am very much thankful that you tried to help me out. But i am sorry your answer is not exactly the answer. You partially answered my 3rd ques (What Env Variables need to be set ?) and i haven't set any env variable to make it work. the automatically generated opencv cmake config file is taking care of OpenCV_DIR variable. So, your partial answer is not helping here. If its only about me, i'd be happy to accept your answer as answer, but since it won't help other readers, i am sorry but i can't mark your answer accpeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @berak, stated in the comment, I installed OpenCV Package for Cygwin using Cygwin Ports. (Without any src or requiring any build, simple install only).
Had to tweak my `CMakeLists.txt` a little but it compiled well.

```
##### CMakeLists.txt ########
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4) 
PROJECT (test)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED )

set( NAME_SRC
    src/main.cpp    
    src/mytest.cpp    
)

set( NAME_HEADERS       
    include/mytest.hpp
)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
add_executable( test ${NAME_SRC} ${NAME_HEADERS} )
include_directories(/usr/include /usr/include/opencv2 /usr/include/opencv ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
link_directories(/usr/lib ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
target_link_libraries(test opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc)
```

(Now, I have totally different trouble of runtime error : `Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display`, but its another story of not having XServer on Cygwin)

Answer (score 1):

The variable should be called `OpenCV_DIR`, it must have the same capitalization as in `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will do that. But i as berak stated in comment, i can't use libs of VS for cygwin. i have to start from there.

Answer (score 0):

First take the following steps to build opencv using visual studio and cmake gui.

1. Clone into the opencv source code repo

`$ git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git`

2. Navigate inside the folder and checkout to the specified version

`$ git checkout 3.0.0`

3. Create a build directory and build opencv in there using CMake and visual studio. Note that by default opencv will build dynamic libraries unless you enable the option of building opencv static libraries.
4. Once done you should handle the environment variables. Create a variable named OpenCV_DIR and point it to the build directory of opencv. Then update your PATH variable to have new opencv `dll` files added. Usually they can be found in the directory `opencv\build\bin\Release` assuming you have built opencv in `Release` mode

Then set up your project `CMakeList.txt` as follows

```
find_package(OpenCV  REQUIRED)  

include_directories(    
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}     
)

target_link_libraries(test
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

The command `find_package(OpenCV  REQUIRED)` finds the opencv configuration files in the directory "opencv/build", aka the directory in which you have built opencv (That's why you should set the value of the variable `${OpenCV_DIR}` to this directory so the command `find_package` can find the required files in there).

The two variables `{OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${OpenCV_LIBS}` have already been set in those configuration files. So you should be all set.